# VSCode messes up indentation in Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, indentation

I am using VSCode (+ some java plugins) to do some core java work and the experience is very good so far. My team members, most of whom use Eclipse, complain that I mess up the spacing/indentation on every commit; sometimes even for lines that I don't change.

How do I prevent VSCode from doing that?

Michael

Comment: You should either use the same [tool and] settings as your colleagues or discuss with them about using plugins for automatic editor configuration. Editorconfig works well and is supported by VSCode and should be supported by Eclipse too, and the configuration file can be committed and shared among all team members.

Answer (score 0):

these settings might can give you some helps:

1. "editor.insertSpaces": true,
2. "editor.detectIndentation": false,
3. "editor.tabSize": 4,

comes from:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings.

and these commands(click the 'Spaces:x' on the bottom right of vscode):

"Convert Indentation to Spaces",

"Convert Indentation to Tabs",

and so on...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!